# POST/Redirect/GET with Error handling

Tags: php, forms, session, post-redirect-get

The reason for this post is that I am trying to avoid the "form re submission error" that most browsers give off when a form is refreshed.

Take the following example:

The user is on a page called **signpetition.php** and shown a basic HTML form:

```
<div id="sign-errors" style="display: none;">
</div>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="sign petition" />
</form>
```

So, the user clicks the `submit` button and now the POST data will be read and verified.

#### signpetition.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
    {
        // Do some validation

        if($errors == true)
        {
          // What to do here? I want to go back to the last page, but keep the errors. Should I store them in a session variable and then unset them after their use? I feel as though there must be a better solution to this.

            $_SESSION['error'] = "the error";
            header('Location: '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , true, 303);
        exit;

        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['success'] = "your petition was successfully signed!";
            header('Location: '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , true, 303);
        exit;
        }
    }
        ?>
```

So, to sum things up:

> I want to avoid the form re submission issue, which is why I'm using
>   the header redirection in my code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the question is...

Comment: Which part of the question is not clear? I will do my best to fix that.

Comment: Well, you state what you want it to do, state your code and why you are doing it that way... But I don't see an actual question.  I don't know if it's not working, if it is.  And if it doesn't work, what is it doing?  Ok, I see what happened, I didn't look for the question inside the comments on the code, I was expecting to see it in the post, not the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users are being redirected, then there should never be a form re-submission.

Redirect them to `submitted.php` and use the following:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){ echo'the error';}
else if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){ echo'your petition was successfully signed!');}
else{ echo 'unknown error.'; }
```

Comment: The thing is, they are not being redirected. In this case, I want to either give the user a message saying "you signed the petition (success)" or "something went wrong (failure)". This would show up on the same page that the form was on.

Comment: So, using SESSION variables in this case isn't a bad idea? That was my initial question, I felt as though there had to be a better way rather than using SESSION vars.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with `$_SESSION`. Additionally, in a website without user accounts, it can help keep a user from voting too often.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I wanted to add that there is nothing wrong with your original solution regarding storing a message in the SESSION object for a single use.  This is a common practice known as "Flash Messages", which are messages stored in the session that are deleted when read a single time.  The technique was made popular by Rails.  A PHP summary is below:

http://www.phpdevtips.com/2013/05/simple-session-based-flash-messages/