# Releasing a passed variable with PHP

Tags: php, variables, release

I am passing some variables to a page using javascript and PHP to receive it.

Essentially, I receive the variable like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['itemId']>0)
```

This will make the code go into a PHP argument to add an item to a cart.

The issue comes when the user continues surfing the site (i.e. he goes to Checkout). If he wants to come back to the previous page, the 'add' variable is somehow still there and the code with get into the Add to cart argument and add another item to the cart, while this should not happen.

How could I release the variable after I have used it? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't release it. you use post/redirect/get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306758/post-redirect-get-with-error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the parameters still being in the query string. To prevent this you need to implement the [`POST/REDIRECT/GET` pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: is that the only option? "the reason why it happens is because you need to use this pattern" sounds really odd!

Comment: I don't think my answer quite states it like that.

Comment: +1 for a generic (rather than your specific) description of how to prevent this.

Comment: Where should I add the POST REDIRECT thing?

Comment: We're not here to spoon feed people.

Comment: @samyb8foo [This tutorial](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) should show you how it works with PHP

Comment: I put `header( "Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); exit();` after my PHP and I get "This webpage has a redirect loop" !!